# C++ Persistent Vector, fill vector with data from a text file

Tags: c++, dynamic, vector

i am currently trying to learn some C++ and now i got stuck in an exercise with vectors. So the task is to read ints from a text file and store them in the vector which should be dynamic.

I guess there is something wrong with the while-loop?
If I start this, the program fails and if I set the vector size to 6, I get
6 0 0 0 0 0 as output.

Thanks for any hints.

```
int main()
{
const string filename = "test.txt";
int s = 0;
fstream f;
f.open(filename, ios::in);
vector<int> v;

if (f){
    while(f >> s){
        int i = 0;
        v[i] = s;
        i = i+1;
    }

  f.close();
}

for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    cout << v[i] << "\n";
}
```

}

Comment: You keep setting `v[0]` because `i` is `0` every time. By the way, `v` is empty and `v[0]` does not actually exist. You want to do `v.push_back(s);` and `for (auto &&n : v) std::cout << n << ',';`.

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't grow the vector. It is empty and cannot hold any `int`s. You'll need to either resize it every time you want to add another `int` or you use `push_back` which automatically enlarges the vector.
2. You set `i = 0` for every iteration so you would change the first value of the vector every iteration instead of the next one.

Go for:

```
    v.push_back(s);
```

in your loop and

```
for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) { // ...
```

> #### Remark:
>
> You normally don't hardcode vector sizes/bounds. One major point about using `std::vector` is its ability to behave dynamically with respect to its size. Thus, the code dealing with vectors should not impose any restrictions about the size of the vector onto the respective object.
>
> Example:
>
> `for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){ cout << v[i] << "\n"; }`
>
> requires the vector to have at least 6 elements, otherwise (less than 6 ints) you access values out of bounds (and you potentially miss elements if `v` contains more than 6 values).
>
> Use either
>
> `for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){ cout << v[i] << "\n"; }`
>
> or
>
> `for(std::vector<int>::const_iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i)
>   { 
>     cout << *i << "\n"; 
>   }`
>
> or
>
> `for(auto i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i)
>   { 
>     cout << *i << "\n"; 
>   }`
>
> or
>
> `for(int x : v){ cout << x << "\n"; }`
>
> or
>
> `for(auto && x : v){ cout << x << "\n"; }`
>
> or
>
> `std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int x){ std::cout << x << "\n"; });`
>
> or variants of the above which possibly pre-store `v.size()` or `v.end()`
>
> or whatever you like as long as you don't impose any restriction on the dynamic size of your vector.

Answer (score 0):

Error is this line `int i = 0;`
because you declare i=0 every time in while-loop.
To correct this move this line outside from loop.

**Note:** this will work, if you declare v like normal array for example `int v[101]` 
When you use `std vectors` you can just push element at the end of vector with `v.push_back(element);`

Comment: Also, I think >> is a binary operator for bit shifting to the right. Maybe you want the operator > ( bigger than)?

Comment: @ChemiCalChems : That part is correct. >> is used while reading from streams.

Comment: True, didn't think about f as a stream, but rather like a variable. Sorry for the mistake. std::cout << "lol";

Comment: @ChemiCalChems yes, >> is a binary operator for bit shifting, but as well >> is using for loading data from stream( fstrem,iostream)

Comment: @encrypt Yes, I know. I just didn't notice f was of type fstream.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the line `i= 0`. Fixing that will give an issue in the line `v[i] = s`.

You always initialise `i` to `0` in the while loop, and that is responsible for the current output. You should shift it out of the while loop.

After fixing that, you have not allocated memory to that vector, and so `v[i]` doesn't make sense as it would access memory beyond bounds. This will give a segmentation fault. Instead, it should be `v.push_back(i)`, as that adds elements to the end of a vector, and also allocates memory if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `std::vector` you can use `v.push_back(i)` to fill this vector

Answer (score 0):

```
v[i] = s; //error,you dont malloc room for vector
```

change into : `v.push_back(s);`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @MohitJain Sure it does not mention all issues in the code, but calling `v[i]` without pushing elements still leads to undefined behavior. This half-answers the question.